# Tax treatment of call option that expires in the money

Tags: united-states, income-tax, call-options

Suppose I buy a deep-in-the-money call option, it expires in-the-money, and I take delivery of the underlying stock at the strike price. Will a realized loss equal to the premium of the option be recorded according to US tax law?

It appears to me that the wash sale rule will apply, but I do not sell the option at a loss. It just expires in-the-money, and I take delivery of the underlying stock.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The premium of the option will become part of the cost basis for the stock, meaning the cost basis of your stock is the strike price of the option plus the premium paid. There is no tax consequence until you sell the stock that you received. The price you sell the stock for minus the cost basis will determine if you had a gain or a loss.

The category of the gain/loss (long- or short-term) is determined by the time period that you hold the *stock*. Even if you held an option for more than a year, you have to hold the *stock* for at least a year do get long-term capital loss/gain treatment.

From [IRS Pub 550](https://www.irs.gov/publications/p550):

> If you exercise a call, add its cost to the basis of the stock you bought. If you exercise a put, reduce your amount realized on the sale of the underlying stock by the cost of the put when figuring your gain or loss. Any gain or loss on the sale of the underlying stock is long term or short term depending on your holding period for the underlying stock.

Wash sale rules do not apply here, since you didn't realize any loss that would trigger a wash sale.

Comment: The reason I referred to the wash sale rule is that if I buy an out-of-the-money call and let it expire a loss is recorded. Similarly, a loss equal to the premium is also incurred on the in-the-money option if I don't close the position before expiry. But since I am taking delivery of the stock which is a "substantially identical security" to the expired call the premium of the option is added to the cost basis of the stock. So the rule you cite is consistent with a "wash sale interpretation" of the situation. There is not an actual sale but the call expiring is like a sale made at price 0.

Comment: You do not realize a loss when your long call is assigned.  The option's cost is folded into the cost basis of the stock purchase.  Assignment, expiration and closing an option position are handled differently for tax purposes.

Comment: "Similarly, a loss equal to the premium is also incurred on the in-the-money option if I don't close the position before expiry." Not true. Read my answer and the IRS pub again.

Comment: para 2 is fascinating !

Answer (score 0):

You do not have a realized loss on the option. There is no involvement with the wash sale rule.

When you exercise a long call to buy the underlying, your cost basis of the stock is the premium paid plus the strike price (ignoring commissions if you're still paying them).

Your gain  will be long term or short term depending on your holding period for the underlying stock.

See page 58 of IRS Publication 550 for details on how options are handled.